# Can I make an in-camera multi-row panorama (Brenizer) with my Fuji camera?

Tags: panorama, brenizer-method, fujifilm-xt10

I recently tried the Brenizer method but found that it is tedious compared to just using the panoramic mode on my Fuji XT-10 which automatically stitches the photos together. The problem is that I can only swipe horizontally or vertically when in panoramic mode but not both. Is there any way one can do in-camera multi-row panoramas?

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't.**

The panorama mode on your camera is very basic, all it does it roughly stitch the edges. In order to correctly make a Brenizer you need to do a more in depth blending that takes in to account lens distortion and vignetting.  That is something that takes a powerful computer a few minutes to do, so your camera certainly wouldn't be able to do it well.